# Login broken for Software Center recommendations

Tags: software-center

I tried to turn on recommendations for Ubuntu Software Center. It asked me for a username and password, so I tried entering what I thought was my Ubuntu One login. Now it seems to silently fail getting recommendations and it no longer asks me for Software Center credentials.

When I run USC from the terminal, I see this message:

```
2012-05-27 16:16:42,919 - softwarecenter.backend.spawn_helper - WARNING - got error from helper: 'WARNING:__main__:401: {'status': '401', 'content-length': '22', 'via': '1.1 sumac.canonical.com:3128 (squid/2.7.STABLE7)', 'x-cache': 'MISS from sumac.canonical.com', 'x-cache-lookup': 'MISS from sumac.canonical.com:3128', 'expires': 'Sun, 27 May 2012 23:16:39 GMT', 'vary': 'Authorization,Accept-Encoding', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'server': 'Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)', 'last-modified': 'Sun, 27 May 2012 23:16:39 GMT', 'etag': '"7e287fc885d9fdcf42da3a12f38572c1"', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=2592000', 'cache-control': 'max-age=0', 'date': 'Sun, 27 May 2012 23:16:39 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'www-authenticate': 'OAuth realm="SoftwareCenter Agent"'}'
```

401 is "Unauthorized", so I'm pretty sure there's a problem with the login information I supplied (and I'd say there's some room for improvement in the interface).

Is there any way to reset it to ask me for login information again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't know why you are having the problem(unless you typed your password incorrectly), I can answer your question on how to reset the login info.

Open the dash and start typing "password" , the application "Passwords and Keys" will come up.  When you open the application you will see the following.
[image]

If you click on the arrow the password list will open and you will be able to right click on the password for the Software Center.

[image]

On the right click menu you will be able to delete this password.

After you delete this password you will be have to "Turn on Recommendations" again in the menu of the Software Center.  It will bring up the window that will allow you to sign up or log in to your existing account.

After doing the above you will have a new password file for the Software Center.  if that was your only problem it will be resolved, if not I have exhausted the extent of my limited knowledge and will be of no further use to you. Hope I was able to help.

Comment: Fantastic answer! I still haven't figured out how to not get the 401 error, but I so totally have the login prompt back now!